# show if on manatory question in docassemble and non-functional continue button

Tags: docassemble

I have an interview which is only 2 mandatory questions. I am getting a non-functional continue button after the first mandatory question (that is, the user can't actually continue), but only when the field remains hidden. I assume this has something do do with the `show if`. Any suggestions? As far as I can tell the javascript on the button is exactly the same in both cases.

Is there an easy fix, and is there anything I can / should learn about `docassemble` from this error?

Relevant portions of .yml file:

```
---
mandatory: True
progress: 90
question: |
    Thank you for completing this survey.
fields:
    - We are always trying to get better, and we're sorry we couldn't help you. Please tell us what you were hoping we could assist you with.
        input type: area
        required: False
        show if:
            code: |
                not is_eligible
---
mandatory: True
question: Thank you for your interest!
buttons:
  - Exit: exit
  - Restart: restart
progress: 100
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1.2.42 or later, this should work.